# Lagrange - Cauchy inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let be $0<a<b$ and $f(x)=\ln(x)$. According to Lagrange's theorem there is at least one point such that:
 $$f'(c) = \frac{f{(b)}-f{(a)}}{b-a}$$

Prove that $$\sqrt{ab} < c < \frac{a+b}{2}$$

I got the derivative of $f(x)=\ln(x)$ and then replaced x by c. The same thing
for $f{(a)}, f{(b)}$ replacing them by $\ln(a) , \ln(b)$, but still there is no
obvious way of going from this point on. I need some support here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct approach works: translating everything in terms of $u=\frac{b-a}a\geqslant0$, the inequalities to prove become, after some simplifications,
$$
u\leqslant(1+u)\log(1+u)\leqslant u(1+\tfrac12u).
$$
Since these are equal at $u=0$, it suffices to consider the derivatives, which yields the sufficient condition $0\leqslant\log(1+u)\leqslant u$. This is obviously true for every $u\geqslant0$ hence you are done.

Comment: very nice and short proof. Thanks. In fact, i see that the trick is to reduce all the thing to a single variable.